# Генерация строки?

Tags: c, строки

Как сгенерировать строку в си?

Например в Python я б сделал так:

```
a = ''

for i in range(10):
a += '#'

print(a)
```

Comment: строка - это массив байт. так что `for(i=0;i<10;i++) a[i]='#';` a[10]=0;`

Comment: Строка в языке С - это массив символов с нулевым символом в конце. Так что сначала вам надо решить, каким образом вы собираетесь создавать сам массив (то, о чем в Python вам беспокоиться не приходилось). Именно это будет сутью вопроса в С. А уже заполнить его символами `#` или чем еще - не проблема.

Comment: В питоне можно написать a = 10 * "#"

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код в переводе:

```
char a[11] = {0};
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    a[i] = '#';
puts(a);
```

Примерно так.
Есть и другие варианты...

Если динамически...

```
int n = 20;
char * a = (char)malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1));
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    a[i] = '#';
a[n] = 0;
puts(a);

// и, по окончании работы, когда строка более не нужна
free(a);
```

Comment: а как в строке `for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)` изменить 10 на введенное число?(или переменную)

Comment: @lalalala ну вот прямо так взять и написать вместо числа 10 переменную (ну и память под строку тогда динамически выделять)

Comment: @lalalala См. дополненный ответ

Comment: @Harry, + `memset(a, '#', 10);` :-)

Comment: Звездочка  потерялась -- `char * a = (char *)malloc(...` (Впрочем, на Си тип можно не приводить, поскольку `void *`, который возвращает malloc автоматически приводится к любому указателю)

Comment: @avp Да, можно, но обычно обязательно находится кто-то, кто вопрошает - почему не приведен... :) Спасибо за поправку.

Comment: @PinkTux `memset(a, '#', 10)` - не дословный перевод :)